# Attach Capacity Provider to a ECS Cluster created in different Cloudformation stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

My team's current task is to develop an **ECS Cluster** to be able to migrate from Elastic Beanstalk.

Since we have our entire infrastructure in Cloudformation we had to stich this implementation to our current templates.

The idea is to have the cluster created separately with the underlying infrastructure that will be shared between the services that will eventually be deployed to the cluster.

There is a different template for the **empty** ECS Cluster and another for the Services (and all resources specific to Services).

The capacity providers are created with (and attached to) the services. From what I could find there is no way in Cloudformation to make a capacity provider appear as part of the cluster after the cluster is created. The capacity provider appears on the Services but not on the cluster and the Service ends up with no resources to provision its tasks.

The workaround I have right now is to define a lambda as a custom resource to call the `putClusterCapacityProvider` action, and pass an empty array to the `defaultCapacityProviderStrategy` property.

This strategy is working but feels a little too hacky. Am I missing something? Is there another way to have the capacity providers appear on the cluster after the cluster is created?

Comment: It shoudn't feel "hacky". Custom resources are develop to fill out all the gaps the AWS left in CFN. You have one such case now. In fact, when working with CFN, developing costume resources is a norm as CFN is very limited.

Comment: Yes you're right, perhaps hacky is not the correct word. But it feels like something that is fundamental for a capacity provider to work needs to be customized.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation has been updated to enable Capacity Provider tuning on existing Clusters via AWS::ECS::ClusterCapacityProviderAssociations.

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/managing-compute-for-amazon-ecs-clusters-with-capacity-providers/ for details